# How to run Jmeter window script on Mac

Tags: windows, macos, jmeter

I have created some Jmeter scripts on Windows. Now want to run same scripts on Mac.
Can someone suggest if I can run already built Windows scripts on Mac? What are steps to do so OR How to create and run Jmeter scripts on Mac in non GUI mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JMeter is not OS dependent. So the same scripts which are working in windows should in work in MAC as well.

> JMeter is a 100% Java application and should run correctly on any system that has a compliant Java implementation.

1. Download JMeter. ( You have to have java installed in your MAC)
2. To run the script in non-gui mode, you have to just add `sh` before the same window non-gui command. Expecting your .jmx file is in /bin folder, use the below command

`sh jmeter -n -t Test.jmx -l Test1.jtl`

Comment: it works thanks for sharing the command to run jmeter in non gui mode on mac os

Comment: No problem and welcome. If it resolved your problem then kindly accept my answer and upvote. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

JMeter is cross-platform so there should not be any problems with running scripts on other operating system. Just follow simple rules:

1. Make sure that you use the same JMeter version on Windows and Mac, [it is recommended to always stick to latest](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) available release ([JMeter 3.3](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-3.3) as of now)
2. If your test relies on external data sources (i.e. CSV files used in the [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)) you will need to copy them over to Mac machine
3. Avoid using full paths as [different operating systems represent paths differently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Representations_of_paths_by_operating_system_and_shell) so copy any required files to JMeter's "bin" folder and reference them by file name only.

Example steps to open JMeter GUI on Mac:

- Download and install [Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
- Open [Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(macOS)) application
- Download JMeter as:

  ```
  wget http://www-us.apache.org/dist//jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-3.3.tgz
  ```
- Unpack JMeter

  ```
  tar xf apache-jmeter-3.3.tgz
  ```
- Go to the unpacked folder

  ```
  cd apache-jmeter-3.3/bin
  ```
- Run JMeter

  ```
  ./jmeter
  ```

Comment: this answer is really useful as clearly describing all required steps at one place, thanks !